# Close CMD window that have been opened through “/c start /wait” in Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

Is there a way to close CMD windows that have been opened through "/c start /wait" in Java?
I use ProcessBuilder to launch a process in a new CMD window to see what is going on in that application:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", cmdString);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Is there a way to shot down / close applications that have been started this way?

ALTERNATIVELY:  Is there a way to open a command line application in a new window without going too fancy?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Could you please add a concrete example of using `start` command in this way?

Comment: /c start /wait C:/bin/read.exe -f D:/test.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the START and /WAIT, and use Process.destroy() to destroy the CMD.

Comment: Without the START command you cannot open command prompt though.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill the process through

```
Process p = pb.start();
p.destroy();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I know of destroy - is does not close the window opened with "/c start /wait", however.